# How to get window using TestStack.White

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I have already get the top level Window by calling:

```
Window win = Desktop.Instance.Windows().Find(...);
```

But exception occurs when getting sub window:

```
IUIItem item = win.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("The Name"));
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'TestStack.White.AutomationException'
>   occurred in TestStack.White.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to get Name=The Name

Sub window info from Inspect.exe:

```
Name:                                 "The Name"
ControlType:                          UIA_PaneControlTypeId (0xC371)
LocalizedControlType:                 "Dialog"
BoundingRectangle:                    {l:96 t:38 r:1917 b:1078}
IsEnabled:                            true
IsKeyboardFocusable:                  false
HasKeyboardFocus:                     false
ProcessId:                            15496
RuntimeId:                            [2A.140BD8]
FrameworkId:                          "Win32"
ClassName:                            "#32770"
NativeWindowHandle:                   0x140BD8
IsControlElement:                     false
IsContentElement:                     false
ProviderDescription:                  "[pid:14492,hwnd:0x140BD8 Main:Microsoft: Container Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Nonclient:Microsoft: Non-Client Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:            0
LegacyIAccessible.Name:               "The Name"
LegacyIAccessible.Role:               Dialog (0x12)
LegacyIAccessible.State:               (0x100000)
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable:         false
IsDragPatternAvailable:               false
IsDockPatternAvailable:               false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable:         false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:     false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable:           false
IsGridPatternAvailable:               false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:             false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:      false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:  true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable:       false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable:        false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:         false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:         false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:             false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:      false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:          false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable:        false
IsStylesPatternAvailable:             false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:  false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:          false
IsTablePatternAvailable:              false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable:          false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable:           false
IsTextPatternAvailable:               false
IsTextPattern2Available:              false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:             false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:          false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable:         false
IsValuePatternAvailable:              false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:             false
```

I haven't found too much info from TestStack.White https://github.com/TestStack/White.
I suspect it is because the sub window isn't an Automation control.

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is not a good idea to look for all desktop windows. You should launch your application providing application path:

```
TestStack.White.Application app = TestStack.White.Application.Launch(applicatonFullPath);
```

Then you should get main window for your application:

```
mainWinDow = app.GetWindows().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name == "YOUR MAIN WINDOW NAME");
```

Your sub window is probably a modal window. You can get it like his:

```
var modalWindows = mainWinDow.ModalWindows();

modalWindow = modalWindows.Where(x => x.Name == "The Name").FirstOrDefault();
```